# Is it possible to remove horizontal lines in Kable kableextra with html option?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I am trying to create a table using kable/kableextra without showing the horizontal lines in the table except for the first row which is the row names.

````
```
{r echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, position = "left") %>%
  row_spec(0, align = "c",bold=T ) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T)
```
````

In the code above there is a line below the first row, which I like since those are row names, but there are lines between every row which I would like to remove.

Ideally I would like to have a slightly thicker line at the top at bottom of this table.  Similar to the booktabs look in LaTeX.

I have read the documentation but the CSS is beyond me.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

What you need is to set `booktabs = T` argument inside `kable`.
In your example, just change the following line of code:

```
kable(dt, "html")
```

to:

```
kable(dt, "html", booktabs = T)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can include a **LaTeX** table in your **html** doc as an image, but you need a *complete* LaTeX distribution  (not tinytex) and the R package **magick** (+Ghostscript if you are on Windows).

Replace

```
kable(dt, "html") %>%
```

with

```
kable(dt, "latex", booktabs=T) %>%
```

and add

```
  kable_as_image()
```

as last line (dont forget the pipe symbol).  The following code works for me:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt, "latex", booktabs=T) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, position = "left") %>%
  row_spec(0, align = "c",bold=T ) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  kable_as_image()
```
````

Ref: See page 24 here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Can't provide a full answer, but I was able to suppress the horizontal lines by altering the CSS for the table in the `row_spec()` function.

```
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt, "html") %>%
kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "left") %>%
row_spec(1:4, extra_css = "border-bottom-style: none")
```

Though this doesn't seem to do anything when included in a `Rmarkdown` document, it does work for `Quarto` documents.

[image]